# Converting commas to dots from excel file in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this kind of column in excel file:

```
Numbers
   13.264.999,99
  1.028,10
756,4
  1.100,1
```

So when I load it with `pd.read_excel` some numbers like `756,4` get converted to `756.4` and become floats while other 3 from the example above remain the same and are strings.

Now I want to have the column in this form (type float):

```
Numbers
13264999.99
1028.10
756.4
1100.1
```

However when converting the loaded column from excel using this code:

```
df["Numbers"]=df["Numbers"].str.replace('.','')
df["Numbers"]=df["Numbers"].str.replace(',','.')
df["Numbers"]=df["Numbers"].astype(float)
```

I get:

```
Numbers
13264999.99
1028.10
nan
1100.1
```

What to do?

Comment: Have you tried to add the param `thousands='.'`, according to: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html.

Comment: No it does not work for my case, as you can see there are some white spaces in excel file so the other 3 numbers are loaded as strings so the thousands parameters does not work on them.

Comment: Maybe you can share your excel-file somehow.

Comment: Sounds highly unlikely, the `thousands` seperator should work here, even though there are whitespaces.

Comment: It does not as the values with whitespaces are imported as strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so I managed to solve this issue:

So first I convert every value to string and then replace every comma to dot.
Then I leave last dot so that the numbers can be converted to float easily:

```
df["Numbers"]=df["Numbers"].astype(str).str.replace(",", ".")
df["Numbers"]=df["Numbers"].str.replace(r'\.(?=.*?\.)', '')  
df["Numbers"]=df["Numbers"].astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the comment by Anton vBR, using the parameter `thousands='.'`, you will get the data read in correctly.

Comment: Just guessing, but perhaps solving the white-spaces first and then converting to float immediately after will work?

Answer (score 0):

You can try reading excel with default type as string

```
df=pd.read_excel('file.xlsx',dtype=str)
```